# `rails` タグについて

Tags: サポート, 完了, タグの別名の提案

`rails` タグは Ruby on Rails に関する投稿に付けられているかと思います。

`ruby-on-rails` のタグシノニムとして `rubyonrails` がありますが、`rails` はタグシノニムでなく独立したタグとなっており、同一内容を示すタグが重複して存在している状況かとおもいます。

`rails` を `ruby-on-rails` のタグシノニムとして登録いただくことは可能でしょうか？

Comment: 英語版SOでも[同様のsynonyms](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby-on-rails/synonyms)設定がされていました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

railsをruby-on-railsのタグシノニムにしました。